# MS Excel/Power Bi/Python Program for Budget Breakdown by Delimiters

Tags: python, excel, powerbi

I am trying to develop a program using MS Excel or MS Power Bi with Python Integration or only Python that will auto calculate budget comparisons between the different categories in comparison to a total cost. In addition, I would love for the program to recognize different categories and sub categories and compare these cost to each other or the total.

I've created an example in which a start up company would have a total $20,000,000 cost to start. This total cost comes from 3 categories: planning, services and subscriptions for programs, and lastly office construction. The office construction cost is further broken down into two offices: the ABC location and the XYZ location. The ABC location has a further cost breakdown into 2 sections: the server room and the bathrooms. The cost of the server room is broken further into: ethernet, computers, and air condition. The computer costs can further be broken down into 7 categories and so forth (PLEASE SEE THE ATTACHED).

To help the program recognize categories, sub categories, and further sub categories, I've assign a cost breakdown structure code using delimiters. For example, the main categories are assigned a CBS code of 1, 2, and 3. The sub categories would be labelled as 1.1 or 1.2 or 3.1 or 3.2 etc. Further classification would be coded as 3.1.1 or 3.1.2 and so forth.

In my attached example, I did a basic cost analysis (cost of interest/sub category or category or total cost and multiplied it by 100% to get a percentage). For example, the "round sink bowl" costs $2,150,000 which is 53.75% of the costs associated with the total cost of "white marble sinks" ($2,150,000/$4,000,000 * 100%) or it makes up 13.11% of the total "office construction costs" ($2,150,000/$16,395,000 * 100%).

I would love to try and do this problem using Power Bi with or without Python integration so that I can make visuals to easily show this. For example, I could have a pie chart that shows which of the three categories of planning, services and subscriptions for programs, and lastly office construction using most of the total budget.

In my example, I manually calculated each point on excel which wasn't too bad as I did not have a large data set. However, my main goal is to create a program that I could theoretically copy and paste a cost breakdown structure sheet of nay size and have the program auto calculate and do cost analysis on between any categories.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.
[Example budget breakdown sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrrwi.png)

As I stated above, I believe sorting and splitting the data by delimiters may be the key to do this on Power Bi. I am just unsure how to get Power Bi to start doing the cost analysis afterwards.

I am open to keeping it within Excel only if that is viewed as the best choice of using python within or not within power bi if that is a better route.

Again, my main goal is to create a program that I could theoretically copy and paste a cost breakdown structure sheet of nay size and have the program auto calculate and do cost analysis on between any categories instead of having to spend days doing the work by hand on EXCEL.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77247726/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would you like to apply `upwork.com` instead?